# get the value of other DropDownList in Jquery after change the option of the first DropDownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, ddl

I select other option on one of my ddl and I succeded on getting that value,but in simultaneously I want to get option on other ddl in the code.
How can I get the other ddl option....?
I put here a code example of my issue:

```
<select id="someIdName" class="selectMenuFromHour" onchange="someFunc(this)">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">(none)</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<select id="someIdName" class="selectMenuTillHour" onchange="someFunc(this)">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">(none)</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>

function someFunc(obj) {

    var startHour;
    var endHour;
    if ($(obj).attr('class') == "selectMenuFromHour") {
                startHour = $(obj).val();
             //*need to add the value of the class - selectMenuTillHour !
            }
        if ($(obj).attr('class') == "selectMenuTillHour") {
                endHour = $(obj).val();
           //*need to add the value of the class selectMenuFromHour!
            }

}
```

Comment: You'd have to identify the `select` with something like `getElementById()` and then get the value from that.  However, your `select` elements have the same `id` so the HTML is invalid.

Comment: I did it with getelementbyclassname and I didn't get the option of .value
/:

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var startHour = 0;
    var endHour = 0;
    if ($this.hasClass("selectMenuFromHour")) {
        $this.find('option').each(function(){
            startHour += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
        });
        alert(startHour);
    }
    if ($this.hasClass("selectMenuTillHour")) {
        $this.find('option').each(function(){
            endHour += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
        });
        alert(endHour);
    }

});
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zmjd6bpr/1/).

Comment: @YuvalOr So can you explain?